# state is updating inside the useffect() but component not re- rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching **Image URL list** from a ***getUserCollection*** function which returns promise, initially state is empty in the console but once it gets the response from function,state is being updated in the console but components doesn't re-render for the updated state. I know that If i make a separate component and pass the state as prop then it sure gonna re-render for the updated state. But why it doesn't happen inside the same component? Can anybody help? Also when i pass state(**userCollection**) as second argument inside useEffect then its running infinite times.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getUserCollection } from "../../firebase/firebase";

const CollectionPage = ({ userAuth }) => {
  const [userCollection, setUserCollection] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserCollection(userAuth.uid)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) setUserCollection(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);                                                       
  console.log("updating???", userCollection);    //its updating in console
  return (
    <main className="container">
      <h3>collection page</h3>
      {userCollection.map((url) => (
        <div class="card-columns">
          <div class="card">
            <img
              src={ url}                  // its not updating 
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="user-collection"
              width="100"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

export default CollectionPage;
```

Comment: show a sample  `userCollection` array element data structure.

Comment: [ "url.jpg","url.jpg","url.jpg"] , normal https url one gets from firebase storage, and when i click twice on the link which route to this component, then only images renders else not.

Answer (score 2):

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

"If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing extra work is less of a problem."

The 2nd argument is what triggers your component to rerender, setting that to your state variable userCollection is triggering your useEffect to run each time the state updates - causing an infinite loop because your useEffect updates the state.

What do you want to actually trigger the rerender? If it's supposed to be blank at first, and then only run once to load the images, you could change it to something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!userCollection){
    getUserCollection(userAuth.uid)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) setUserCollection(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  }, [userCollection]);
```

With this logic, the useEffect will only update the state when it is empty. If you're expecting continuous rerenders, you should create a variable that updates when the rerenders should occur.

Comment: if i leave state blank instead of an empty array  initially then in the first occurrence of render . map()  inside jsx will cause error for undefined state.

Comment: you could replace if(!userCollection) with if(userCollection.length === 0) and keep the initialization as an empty array

Comment: i already tried that component is not re rendering and in console  effect running infinite times.

Comment: are you getting errors in the console? if userCollection is being set, it should not run infinite times, if you are getting errors in your console, to get it working you could call setUserCollection in the catch block.